# Identifying Specific Div instead of using .next()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to move the `.step1` div so it won't be right next to the `#step4m` div that way no matter where it is on the page, the code should work the same since it will identify the specific div instead of using `.next()`

The HTML:

```
<div class="step1 marker_show">
    <a id="q1_one" class="step_button s1 run_loading" href="">option 1</a>
    <a id="q1_two" class="step_button s1 run_loading" href="">option 2</a>
</div><!-- STEP 1 END -->

<div id="step4m" class="step4 marker_show">
    <div id="stepend" class="show_end">
        <div id="proceed">
            <div id="if_one">
                <a id="agree1" class="step_button" href="http://link1.com">Continue</a>
            </div>
            <div id="if_two">
                <a id="agree2" class="step_button" href="http://link2.com">Continue</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- STEP 4 END -->
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.run_loading', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
    $('.step4 .loading').show();
    run_loading_run_1('2500');
    run_loading_run_4('2500',q1);
});
```

**UPDATE: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TceWf/)**

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
.nextAll('#step4m:first')
```

However, since IDs must be unique, you could also just write `$('#step4m')`.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TceWf/  The top set of options are the ones I'm trying to get to work but I can't since its not right next to #step4m

Comment: @JoeBobby: Did you try what SLaks suggested? You should be able to just put in `$('#step4m').fadeIn();` instead of the `.next().fadeIn()`.